# C++ Multiple definition of ' ' first defined here

Tags: c++

I know that this subject has already been discussed on this site, I tested the solutions but it doesn't work, I always have the same mistake. Please help me :')

1. Player.cpp

```cpp
#include "Player.hpp"

namespace Player
{
  const char *name = "Jason"; 
}
```

2. Card.cpp

```cpp
#include "Player.hpp"

namespace Player
{
  const char *name = "Jason"; 
}
```

3. Player.hpp

```cpp
namespace Player
{
  extern const char *name;
}
```

Comment: Your linker is correct. Why are you defining name in `Card.cpp`?

Comment: You define `Player::name` in both `.cpp` files. Did you mean to give them different names or something?

Comment: Because I want to use this variable in this file too.

Comment: You can still use it. That is what the declaration in the header gives you.

Comment: Then use it without redefinition

Comment: Ah I see. That is what the **declaration** in the header file is for. You only need the **definition** in one place though. Those are the C++ terms you need to look up the difference in meaning between.

Comment: I want to use one and the same variable in 2 different files

Comment: Yes, just delete the definition from `Card.cpp` and use it.

Comment: Then use it, that declaration in header allows you to use anywhere that header included into. You just need to define it in one and only one .cpp file.

Comment: I assume you have not learned classes yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can have at most one definition of each unique fully-qualified symbol in your program. The linker error you are receiving is occurring because you provide a definition for the symbol `Player::name` in both `Player.cpp` and `Card.cpp`.

You are free to reuse variable names; but the symbol must still be *unique* to avoid these issues. For your particular problem, this may be solved through one of the following:

- **Defining the symbol in a different `namespace`** 

  For example, you could change `Card.cpp` to be:

  ```cpp
  // Symbol is Card::name -- which is different from Player::card
  namespace Card {
      const char* name = ...;
  } // namespace
  ```
- **Defining the symbol as a `static` member of a `struct`/`class`** 

  This could be something like:

  ```cpp
  // Symbol is Player::Card::name -- which is different from Player::card
  namespace Player {
    struct Card {
        static const char* name = ...;
    };
  }
  ```
- **Marking the symbol with internal linkage** 

  This could be done using an unnamed `namespace` (C++11 and above), or `static` (older C++):

  ```cpp
  // Symbol is Player::<some unique name>::name
  namespace Player {
    namespace {
      const char* name = ...;
    }
    // or 'static const char* name = ...;'
  }
  ```

  **note:** This method, unlike the others, cannot be used across different source files. The symbol is "internalized", which means it is unique to the one compilation unit (source file).